# Java Spring Boot : KeyCloak Server : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

2 weeks ago my Spring Boot code was ok. But last week I upgrade my Linux version. Now using Linux 20.04.
Now Always java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group.

Spring boot: 2.3.4.RELEASE
Keycloak : 11.0.3
JDK : OPENJDK 8,11,14.

1. I use JDK 11 but not working.
2. I use JDK 8 but not working.
3. I use JDK 14 but not working.
4. I use windows os and JDK 11 but not working.
5. I change the project build path JRE to 8/11/14 but not working.
6. I also try keycloak version 11.0.2 and 11.0.3. But not working.

I search here and there. Read many articles but didn't find any solution.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I download the previous version of the Spring Tool Suite and use it.
Now the problem is gone.

But still don't know why this problem I face.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Spring Tool Suite 4.9, change the installed JREs to your local JRE 8 or 11.

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs